# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in Typheous when I perform a POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, segmentation-fault, typhoeus

It's really tricky in our production environment( Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga) and curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5) that the POST request become to GET request automatically. Below is the relative log provide by nginx.

```
cache: [GET /login] miss
url->http://localhost:8080/login

About to connect() to localhost port 8080
Expire at 1339680839 / 265363 (300000ms)
Trying 127.0.0.1... * connected
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/typhoeus-0.4.0/lib/typhoeus/multi.rb:141: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
2012/06/14 21:28:59 [error] 29829#0: *6031 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "127.0.0.1:8081", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/login"
```

In fact, we send a POST request to login, but it convert to GET actually.

In our development environment( which is Ubuntu12.04 and curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3), everything goes ok.

Who can explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I upgraded the curl from 7.15 to 7.22. The problem has been solved.